# Best way to run 1k+ queries on MongoDB and nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to run approximately 1,000 queries on MongoDB to check for matches on particular object property.

Please shield your eyes from what is no doubt some extremely amateur code but would appreciate any ways to make this more efficient. It works but takes a long time.

'followers' is an array of Twitter user objects and it is being checked against a database of half a million records.

```
function checkFollowers(followers){
  // check if followers are in DB

  let matches = [];

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log("Connected!");

    async.each(followers, function(item, callback){

      var regex = new RegExp("^" + item.username + "$", 'i')

      dbo.collection("User").findOne({Username : {$regex : regex}},function(err, result) {

        if (err) throw err;

        if(result != null){
          matches.push(result.Username)
        }
,
        callback(null);

      });
    }, function(err){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('All records have been checked');
            db.close();
            console.log("This many matching records " + matches.length)
            console.log(matches)
        }
    });      
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't use mongoDB, but do you have a case insensitive index on `Username`?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
const allUsers = dbo.collection("User").find().toArray();
followers.forEach( follower => {
   var regex = new RegExp("^" + follower.username + "$", 'i')      
   if (allUsers.filter( aUser = > regex.test(aUser))) 
      matches.push(aUser.Username);
})
```

Reading the collection again and again does not make much sense.

Regular expressions are always slow, so you may prefer

```
dbo.collection("User").aggregate([
   {$set: {username_UC: { $toUpper: "$username" } } }
]).toArray();
followers.forEach( follower => {
   if (allUsers.filter( aUser => aUser.username_UC == follower.toUpperCase() )) 
      matches.push(aUser.Username);
})
```

Or even faster:

```
dbo.collection("User").aggregate([
   {$match: {$expr: { $in: [ { $toUpper: "$username" }, followers.map(x => x.toUpperCase()) ] } } }
])
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm not a mongoDb user, but wouldn't `findOne` only find one?.  Not the whole collection.   And in your example what if the user table has millions of users, and the OP only wanted to read 1000?.   Another idea, can mongoDB handle lots of `OR` conditions so that you just build a big `OR` list you can send to `find`?.

Comment: @Keith As the name implies `findOne` will return only one document (or `null` if nothing found)